# Ionic 3 deep-linking and lazy-loading at the same time

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, ionic3, deep-linking

According to what I've read in the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/IonicModule/#forRoot) and [forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-configure-deeplinks-in-appmodule-forroot/66058/4), you enable deep-linking via : **forRoot(appRoot, config, deepLinkConfig)**

```
@ngModule({
  ..
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
    links:[{ component: ContactPage, name: "contact", segment: "contact"},
           { component: HelloPage, name: "hello", segment: "hello" }
          ]
  })
  ...
}) ...
```

This leads to adding **ContactPage** and **HelloPage** to declarations and entryComponents arrays within `@ngModule`, which would not be lazy-loaded.

So, this leads to the question, can you substitute strings, doing away with the imports and double array declaration, and have this?

```
@ngModule({
  ..
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
    links:[{ component: 'ContactPage', name: "contact", segment: "contact"},
           { component: 'HelloPage', name: "hello", segment: "hello" }
          ]
  })
  ...
}) ...
```

and achieve lazy-loading at the same time?

**Update**: Tried with a single Tabs page. I'm guessing it's not working ATM.

[image: Lazy-Loaded Deep-Linked Tabbed Page fail]

Comment: i am getting same problem have you found solution? @jgfmk

Comment: I just stopped using both deep linking and lazy loading. Lazy loading prevented some other functionality from working somewhere in my app IIRC. But I can't remember what that was now - it was so long ago! Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing same error in 2018. It seems deep links and lazy loading don't play well together. I propose to use the following cordova plugin :

https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking