# Ionic Deep Linking

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, deep-linking

I've created my first Ionic app with Deep Linking. 
Had to give up on [lazy-loading with deep links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777446/ionic-3-deep-linking-and-lazy-loading-at-the-same-time) for now...
But I'm confused by the way the URLs stay around when you navigate elsewhere, like back to the home page. How are people working round this? Just doing some kind of URL rewriting?
Or is doing that likely to, break something else?
It seems you can't easily wipe out the URL either, as it comes back again.

I've seen the [Ionic blog](http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/), and the heated discussions in the [Github issues](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9012) about the behaviour.

It seems that the `@IonicPage` gives some control over customising stuff, but that is for lazy-loading/modules only right? Or can you use the annotation without lazy loading?

Any advise on how best to work with this would be appreciated.

I also noticed some other weird behaviour, in that the data structure I used to hold a reference to the HomePage, became undefined, even though it was exported as a constant. It was the initial rootNav when app launches.
I had to do a kludgy hack to work around it, conditioning for it

```
if (page.home != undefined) { //Bug in Ionic perhaps
   this.nav.setRoot(HomePage, params)
   .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log(`Didn't set HOME root: ${err}`);
   }); 
} else {
   this.nav.setRoot(page.component, params)
   .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log(`Didn't set nav root: ${err}`);
    });
}
```

**Chrome console.log**
[image: Chrome console.log]

**PageInterface data structure**
[image: Page Interface]

**Part of constant that lost 'HomePage, in the component key of class I'd imported.**
[image: Code that lost component]

**Is this something others have experienced? Any advice, or glaring errors I'm not seeing. Cheers.**

Comment: It's bizarre about components in my data structure. Randomly today, another object reference called LaunchpadPage is undefined. Yet yesterday it was fine! Thinking of using massive switch to safeguard!

Answer (score 0):

First of all navigation in ionic is quite buggy since version 3.6.0 (especially with tabs) where they refactored the way URLs are generated (they are more readable now). As you already mentioned there are many open issues on github which will be fixed in the next few weeks according to the team (they are very busy currently refactoring the whole framework for v4 of ionic).

To answer you question regarding the IonicPage decorator:
You can also use it without lazy-loading the pages:
In your main module `app.module.ts` you add the following:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      preloadModules: true
    })
],
```

`preloadModules: true` tells ionic you want to load you pages eagerly (not lazy).
And in your `IonicPage` decorators you can configure with which priority the modules are loaded on startup:

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'my-page',
  priority: 'high'
})
```

For the `priority` property the values `high`, `low` and `off` are available. `off` means the page is lazy-loaded. You can find this in the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) of the IonicPage decorator.